# How do I use Perl's localtime with print to get the timestamp?

Tags: perl, built-in

I have used the following statements to get the current time.

```
  print "$query executed successfully at ",localtime;
  print "$query executed successfully at ",(localtime);
  print "$query executed successfully at ".(localtime);
```

**Output**

```
 executed successfully at 355516731103960
 executed successfully at 355516731103960
 executed successfully at Wed Apr  7 16:55:35 2010
```

The first two statements are not printing the current time in a date format.
Third statement only giving the correct output in a date format.

My understanding is the first one is returning a value in scalar context, so it is returning numbers.

Then in the second print I used localtime in list context only, why it's also giving number output.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Perhaps the most important thing you can learn for programming in Perl, is context. Many built-in subroutines, and operators, behave differently depending on the context.

```
print "$query executed successfully at ", localtime, "\n"; # list context
print "$query executed successfully at ",(localtime),"\n"; # list context
print "$query executed successfully at ". localtime, "\n"; # scalar context
print "$query executed successfully at ".(localtime),"\n"; # scalar context

print "$query executed successfully at ", scalar  localtime, "\n"; # scalar context
print "$query executed successfully at ", scalar (localtime),"\n"; # scalar context
```

This can be made clearer by splitting up the statements.

```
my $time = localtime; # scalar context
print "$query executed successfully at $time\n";

my @time = localtime; # list context
print "$query executed successfully at @time\n";
```

Answer (score 10):

The return value of [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) depends on the context. In list context it is a 9-element list, while in scalar context it is a `ctime(3)` value:

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime;
my $now_string = localtime;  # e.g., "Thu Oct 13 04:54:34 1994"
```

Now, [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) provides list context for its arguments. That's why `print localtime` outputs the numbers from the list (without any separator by default). You can force scalar context on `localtime` using either the `.` concatenation operator (like in your 3rd statement) or using [`scalar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html):

```
print "".localtime;
print scalar localtime;
```

Answer (score 7):

[scalar](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) forces scalar context:

```
print scalar localtime ();
```

In the second example, it's clearly a list context so you're just getting a printout of the numbers in a row. For example, try

```
 print join (":", (localtime));
```

and you'll see the numbers joined with a colon.

Answer (score 4):

Both the first and second return the values in the list context but they are probably not what you would expect. The use of parens around localtime simply won't do anything useful. But you can use the following code to get those returned list items separately:

```
@list = ($sec,$min,$hour,$day,$mon,$year_1900,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime;
print join("\n",@list);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the timestamp of the current time,
you can just use function time()